# Tooltipster multiple tooltips within a single tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

ok so i got tooltipster to show a tooltip within a tooltip thanks to louisameline, the issue i'm having now is to get each individual line within the first tooltip to have a seperate tooltip of its own heres what i have upto now

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAjWb/15/)

```
$('#test').tooltipster({
    content: $('<span id="test1">line one</span><br><span id="test2">line two</span><br><span id="test3">line three</span><br><span id="test4">line four</span>'),
    interactive: true,
    functionReady: function(origin){
        var t = origin.tooltipster('elementTooltip');
        $(t).tooltipster({
            content: 'second tooltip',
            position: 'right'
        });
    }
});
```

so each  would have its own tooltip but everything i've tried has just broken the script. can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`Updated Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/QAjWb/16/)***

```
functionReady: function (origin) {
    var t = origin.tooltipster('content');
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        $(t[i]).tooltipster({
            content: 'tooltip for ' + i +'th content',
            position: 'right'
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for...!!!